# Detect change in color of pixel

Tags: c++, css, pixel

I'm new to making programs and I have no idea where to really begin.
However I have this simple idea that I want to turn into reality.

I need to find a red pixel in a blue area on screen. The area is a rectangle from

(x = 86)(y = 457) to  (x = 770)(y = 641) -- that's just can example.

Then get a list of all the pixels within that region and check if they are a certain color like (Red=186, Blue=10, Green=10)
Then 0.2 seconds later check if those pixels that were red are still red.
Then check again 3 times, every 0.2 seconds.

After that tell the program to wait until those pixels turn blue.
When they do open `C:User/User1/documentss/pull.mcs` --random file.

I would like to create this thing, but I have no idea how to get all the pixels within a certain region (since there is thousands and doing it manually won't work) then check their color and finally tell the program to open another program.

The picture attached is what I am working on, this red thing moves and I need to first find where it is and then make sure that the pixel stays red. Eventually the thing will sink and I need a program to start.

Thanks for reading and please give me some suggestions.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvC6t.png

Comment: Maybe use `template matching opencv` instead of finding 1 pixel.

Comment: I think this is not a C++ issue, as C++ does not know what a screen is ... all C++ i/o's are streams (or memory mapped hardware)  If you are using opencv for graphics, search that documentation.  Why the tag css?

Comment: I feel really stupid right now, I didn't think too much about it

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is looking for a solution to a problem like this. This can e accomplished with autohotkey very easily.

"find a red pixel in a blue area on screen. The area is a rectangle from
(x = 86)(y = 457) to (x = 770)(y = 641)"

in this example the red area is irrelevant, we're just looking for the blue pixel

```
PixelSearch, x, y, 457, 770, 770, 641, 0x0000FF, Fast RGB
if (ErrorLevel = 0){    
    MsgBox, Found the pixel at %x%,%y%
}
else MsgBox, We did not find the pixel.

Return
```